# How to write big file efficiently in Haskell

Tags: performance, haskell, io, writefile

Hello i am trying to write a `~1GB` file in a timely manner.Is there any recommended  method.Up until now the process takes somewhere in the order of tens of minutes . Am i wrong in using `Text` should i use `ByteString` ? (I have also used `String`)

```
    pt="d:\\data2.csv"
    cnt=400000000

    main::IO()
    main=do
        let payload=dat
        writeWithHandle pt dat


    dat::Text
    dat=Data.Text.pack "0744442339"


    writeWithHandle::FilePath->Text->IO()
    writeWithHandle path tx=do
        handle<-openFile path WriteMode
        writeTimes cnt handle dat

    writeTimes::Int->Handle->Text->IO()
    writeTimes cnt handle payload= forM_ ([0..cnt])  (\x->Data.Text.IO.hPutStrLn handle payload)
```

I do not understand why it is taking so much in the order of tens of minutes.Initially i was using `writeFile` but i thought that would mean continously opening and closing the `file` for each row so i used `appendFile` to no avail.

Comment: Is it faster if you batch the writes?  Something like `T.replicate 10 dat` or even 1000x.

Comment: Did you compile with optimisations turned on? Writing a 14GB file with more or less what you're doing here takes me about 5 mins on my machine. (Also, you forgot to close your file after writing to it, you should just use `withFile` rather than `openFile` tbh)

Comment: I have  not compiled with optimizations turned on. (I 'm still a beginner).

Comment: Using bytestrings and with optimizations on, your code created a 4GB file in 43s. A main issue here is that `Text` is stored as UTF16 while file output is usually is UTF8, so conversion will require some time. Building a bytestring once, I converted `dat` only once for the whole program. In a real-world scenario, however, you might have a lot of different lines. If skipping `Text` is an option, I'd try to go for that.

Comment: Apparently after i closed the `handle` it worked a lot faster , as **@Cubic** pointed out.

Comment: General advice: text files bigger than a few MB are a bad idea. Use binary formats for all significant amounts of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using a Builder for this, which is an efficient way to fill up buffers and can be written directly to a Handle.

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver ghc-8.6.4 script
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.ByteString.Builder (Builder, hPutBuilder)
import Data.Foldable (fold)
import System.IO (IOMode (WriteMode), withBinaryFile)

pt :: FilePath
pt = "data2.csv"

cnt :: Int
cnt = 400000000

main :: IO ()
main = writeWithHandle pt dat

dat :: Builder
dat = "0744442339"

writeWithHandle :: FilePath -> Builder -> IO ()
writeWithHandle path tx =
  withBinaryFile path WriteMode $ \h ->
  hPutBuilder h $ makeBuilder cnt tx

makeBuilder :: Int -> Builder -> Builder
makeBuilder cnt payload = fold $ replicate cnt $ payload <> "\n"
```

You can keep `payload` as a `Text` value instead if you'd like, and convert to a `Builder` using [`encodeUtf8Builder`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.12/text-1.2.3.1/Data-Text-Encoding.html#v:encodeUtf8Builder).

Comment: How does `dat :: Builder; dat = "0744442339"` work? In GHCi, the same is met with the error `Couldn't match expected type ‘Builder’ with actual type ‘[Char]’`